# Refused to execute script from '*' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api, mime-types, form-submit

I am using a form on my website to update a Google Sheet using Google Forms. It was working fine, but recently I have started receiving the above mentioned error.

Please note, that the data is getting recorded perfectly, its just that the 'alert' is not getting triggered (no response from sheets?) so the user is not able to get a confirmation that his data has been recorded.

This is the script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function postContactToGoogle(){
        var name = $('#name-add').val();
        var email = $('#email-add').val();
        var location=$('#location-add').val();

        if ((email !== "")) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Nt-NaXVnZYHDeEbqTypyq6ZUMKPk9of4fW_U5eaiLjg/formResponse",
                data: {"entry.555826589" : name, "entry.2022783192" : email, "entry.128132944": location},
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                statusCode: {
                    0: function (){
                        $('#name-add').val("")
                        $('#email-add').val("")
                        $('#location-add').val("");

                        //Success message
                        alert("Sweet! We will get in touch soon.");

                    },
                    200: function (){
                        $('#name-add').val("");
                        $('#email-add').val("");
                        $('#location-add').val("");
                        //Success message
                        alert("Sweet! We will get in touch soon.");
                    }
                }
            });
        } else {
            //Error message
            alert("Email is required");
        }
    }
```

PS: My website is hosted on Blogger.

Comment: This could be because of some settings in your files. Try checking this links:   http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project:Support_desk/Problem_with_Javascript and http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Thread:Project:Support_desk/Problem_with_Javascript